# Disable login button when an employee is currently login in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, authentication

Employee Login System using vba userform.
I can capture Employee name and login time and put it in a sheet.  However, an employee who is currently login can still login in the system. I want to stop it from happening.

Here's the screenshot of my form.

[[image]]

Code:

```
Dim CM As Boolean

Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

With Worksheets("May_1st").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0) = UserForm1.txtName.Value
    .Offset(1, 1) = UserForm1.txtEmpID.Value
    .Offset(1, 2) = UserForm1.txtTime.Value
End With

'Unload Me 'Optional: Close Userform1

txtName.Value = ""
txtEmpID.Value = ""
txtEmpID.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub cmdLogOut_Click()

'Worksheets("May_1st").Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

'Unload Me 'Optional: Close Userform On Where Logout Button Is

Dim myLog As Worksheet
Dim myLogSheet As Range

Set myLog = Sheets("May_1st")
Set myLogSheet = myLog.Range("B:B").Find(txtEmpID.Value, , , xlWhole)

If Not myLogSheet Is Nothing Then
myLogSheet.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

Else
txtName.Value = "XXX"

End If

txtName.Value = ""
txtEmpID.Value = ""
txtEmpID.SetFocus


End Sub

Private Sub txtEmpID_Change()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set mySheet = Sheets("Emp_ID")
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("B:B").Find(txtEmpID.Value, , , xlWhole)

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
txtName.Value = myRange.Offset(0, -1)
Else
txtName.Value = "Match not found"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_activate()

'Do
'If CM = True Then Exit Sub
'txtTime = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
'DoEvents
'Loop

Do While CM = False
UserForm1.txtTime = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
DoEvents
Loop

'txtEmpID.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

CM = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of solving this issue but they would depend on understanding how and when the Login form is displayed. I would go about solving this issue weighing these options:

1. **Create and maintain a flag for users who are logged in**

   - This way you can grey out the Login button. A code will run when cursor focus goes out of Emp_ID. Though this might be computationally heavy, it is a matter of just a code implementation.
2. **Create another form for Login and Logout function**

   - You could prompt to ask user details in the current form and with a click to next button open the next form, you could validate if user should login or logout and make the appropriate option to the user

Comment: Hi Rishil.  I just don't know how to come up with that.  I can send you a link  that allows you to download the sample excel file though.

Comment: Hi Frozen Blood, you can send me the file, I could give it a shot

Comment: Hi Rishil Jacob what's ur email?

Comment: hey, had my semesters going on. mail me at rj.nitk@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can store  the logon details to either of

- a hidden sheet
- range name
- Registry (`SaveSettings`)
- the `UserForm` tag
- separate `txt` file etc

Then retrieve the details as part of your code.

Suggest you pick what most suits you.

Comment: Hi brettdj thank you so much for your respond..as of now i'm still trying to come up for any ways to make this happen..reallyx2 having some hard time.

Comment: @frozenblood are you unclear as to how to implement these methods?

Comment: I'm trying to use the .fine(txtEmpID) and then applied the offset to see if the corresponding cell is empty.  If it's empty then that means that that employee is still login.